# ¿Cómo hacer un confirmdialog yes/no en java con prolog?

Tags: java, java-swing, prolog, swi-prolog, jpl

Esta es la regla o predicado en el archivo prolog.

```
sintoma(X):-pregunta('Usted tiene',X).

pregunta(Incognita,X):-write(Incognita),write(' '),write(X),write(' '),write('? si/no,').

enfermedad_sintoma(alergia):-

    sintoma('estornudos'),
    sintoma('ojos llorosos'),
    sintoma('ardor en la nariz'),
    sintoma('picor en la garganta/boca/labios'),
    sintoma('inflamacion de boca/vias respiratorias').
```

Aquí hacemos la consulta de la regla y extraemos el resultado de la regla para posteriormente imprimirla en el 'JOptionPane.showConrimDialog'... pero solo en consola sale la impresión y no en el frame:

```
Int u;
String t2 = "enfermedad_sintoma('alergia')";
Query q2 = new Query(t2);      
u = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿Esta seguro?"+q2.allSolutions().toString(), "Alerta!", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null);
```

Comment: Cual es tu mensaje de error? Funcionan tus reglas? Recuerda en la medida de lo posible poner siempre un [mcve]

Comment: ok pondre todo el codigo

Comment: puedes intentar con `String t2 = "enfermedad_sintoma(Alergia)";` para verificar que no sea un problema de sintaxis?